# Integrate a tool for drawing structural formulas

Tags: feature-request, chemical-formulas

Based on my [previous meta post looking for suitable tools](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/527/finding-a-library-to-allow-drawing-chemical-structures-directly-on-the-site), I propose to add the [ChemDoodle Web Components](http://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/sketcher) for drawing structural formulas to the site.

From the alternatives I've looked at, this seems to be the best choice in my opinion, based on features and UI. It also seems to be under active development.

Drawing the full structural formulas is pretty important in chemistry, being able to do that directly on the site would be very useful.

The functionality that we need here would be mostly the full 2D Sketcher Canvas. Some of the additional features that are available might be useful as well, but I think it makes sense to start with only the 2D drawing part.

Comment: For anyone that's going to look into this on the SE side, http://web.chemdoodle.com/about/advantages is a good summary of the advertised features, particularly the "lightweight" aspects, which are a huge selling point, IMO, though I don't have the tools to run any extensive tests of their claims.